# After disabled Http GET method, how to unit test it?

Tags: java

So in my Spring controller, i have this route

```
@RequestMapping(value = "myroute", method = POST)
public String myRoute(HttpServletRequest) {
    ...
}
```

We use MockMvcBuilder to mock the POST calls.

```
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder post = post(myRouteUrl);
mockMvc.perform(post).andExpect(status().isOK());
```

Now if i just change post to get, the status back is still 200.
So how to verify GET method is failing ?

Using Java 1.8.
Thanks !

Comment: Perform a `GET` and expect a [405 response](https://http.cat/405) ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: when i change post to get in the mockMvc, it's still returning 200. My guess is this mockMvc is not configured the same way with the real controller, but is there an easy way to unit test it without web server running ?

Comment: There's probably a handler that's listening on a `GET` method for the same route. Or a filter that always responds with 200, completely disregarding the status code of the DispatcherServlet or your controllers

Comment: @user3552178 if the webserver is running and you do a real HTTP GET call, what is the response?

Comment: @RoyalBg if web server is running, the real HTTP GET does fail with 404.

Comment: Can we see your MockMvc setup?

Comment: i do not see any special setup for MockMvc, in the setup( ) only this: this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build()

Comment: Is there, by any chance, a possibility that it first sends an `OPTIONS` request and it returns 200 OK, then the subsequent `GET` request returns 404, but what you actually receive is the `OPTIONS` Response? Could you try to enable/disable `dispatchOptions`?

Answer (score 1):

I got a HTTP error 405 when I tried the following. Is there something else missing from the example shown?

This is the controller class I used.

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET;

@RestController
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/myroute", method = GET)
    public String myRoute(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("HERE");
        return "good";
    }
}
```

This is the test class I used.

```
package demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
class MyControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Test
    void myRoute() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder post = post("/myroute");
        mockMvc.perform(post).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
 Error message = Request method 'POST' not supported
          Headers = [Allow:"GET"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

Status expected:<200> but was:<405>
Expected :200
Actual   :405
```

Comment: Do you have server running ? if so this is expected. I'm trying to add unit test, if i shutdown server, the unit test will return 200 which is not right. On the other hand, i don't know if i need a unit test or functional test.

Comment: Regarding if server is running - only in the sense to run the test. Not sure if that answers your question though (and not sure I really understand it). Let me ask though, how are you creating and initializing your mockMvc variable?

Comment: i'm a new Java developer, so not sure if i see all the config. But cannot find any custom settings, pretty much only 1 line:  MockMvcBuilder.webAppContextSetup(...).build(). Certainly my unit test won't work, since MockMvc didn't disable the GET method.